# Where I should store the Wordpress site in Xampp (linux)

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, lampp

I never use Wordpress but I usually use Xampp (Linux) to work.
So, I installed Wordpress and it works fine, if I enter with my browser to `http://localhost/wordpress/` I can see the WP page.

I got from a friend his WordPress site files and stored them in `/opt/lampp/htdocs` like any regular web site, but when I try accessing `http://localhost/folder_name/` I get the `Index of folder_name` and not the actual site.

I noticed that `/opt/lampp/apps/` has a "WP" folder, and inside it - an `htdocs` folder like xampp have.

Where's the correct place to store the WP project ? 
Is it `/opt/lampp/apps/wp/htdocs` or `opt/lampp/htdocs/` ?
How can I get the WP site working and not get the index of / page?

Comment: htdocs is the folder where you keep your application

Comment: ok, but which one? `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` or `/opt/apps/wordpress/htdocs/` ? and if the answer is the first one, why I get the "index of"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put the root of your WordPress installation in the same location you would put anything you want to be able to access at http://localhost.  From what you're saying, it sounds like that is `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`

**The Problem**

WordPress runs just about everything through a database, including it's `siteurl` and `home` directory values.  If you don't have a database at all, nothing is going to work. You'll find more on this problem [Here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/new-install-index-of-showing-up-when-go-to-website/).

**The Hard Fix**

You could try [Migrating](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) your friend's WP install to your XAMPP server, but you'll need their database for that to work.  You could then use a tool like [Wordpress Database Reset](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-database-reset/), which will get you back to basically a fresh install, just with any themes and plug-ins your friend's install included.

**The Easy Fix**

Since it sounds like you want a fresh install with a custom theme or plug-in from your friend, you can just start with a fresh install, and then add any themes and plug-in's in. Installing WordPress is fairly simple since they have a web-based installer to help you get everything set up.  Check out [this guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress).  Once you've got the basic site set up you can import any themes and plug-ins you want from your friend's WordPress installation.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I'll try to fix it today, and tell you whats happend.

Comment: Hey @Mike Knooihuisen, I got the DB of my friend, Do you have any Idea Which rows I need to change make the Word Press works with xampp?

Answer (score 0):

I have read your problem folder path correct is `opt/lampp/htdocs/`
 you need to make all services enable for server.